# Convergent of a series with an arbitrary sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n\in\mathbb{R}_+$ be an arbitrary  increasing sequence of real numbers, and $f(\cdot)\in\mathcal{L}_1[0,\infty)\cap\mathcal{L}_\infty[0,\infty)$.

If  the condition: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\infty$ is satisfied, can I prove that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)f(a_n)<C<\infty$$

for some constant $C$.

Comment: No: supposing $f>0$, recursively define $a_{n+1}$ so that $a_{n+1}-a_n > 1/f(a_n)$, for example.

Comment: @GregMartin 
thanks